# How do I preserve Enums as 'Strings' in ConvertTo-Json cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, convertto-json

`ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet in PowerShell core has a parameter `EnumsAsStrings` which allows JSON to have string representations instead of integer for Enums.
There is no such parameter in Windows Powershell. What will be a solution for complex objects for Windows PowerShell without manually casting individual members to their string values?

Comment: My understanding this is possible to do with using third party JSON converters somehow but I failed to find a working example so far